# Fetch Child Documents from Cosmos Db with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have the a Author object and it has a list of books as child objects as follows

```
public class Author
    {
        public Guid AuthorId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Book> Books { get; set; } = new HashSet<Book>();
    }
```

This is stored in CosmosDb as two separate documents (as this is how EF seems to write to Cosmos).

However if I do the following

```
using (var context = new BookStoreDbContext())
            {
                var list = context.Authors;

                foreach (var author in list)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(author.FirstName + " " + author.LastName);

                    foreach (var book in author.Books)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t" + book.Title);
                    }
                }
            }
```

The Books collection is empty...

How do I get it to return the books?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. I needed to add the following code in the BookStoreDbContext

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().OwnsMany(t => t.AccountUsers);
        }
```